# Hash sequential 64 bit number uniformly into 8 bits?

Tags: c#, hash, integer

I'm looking for a hash algorithm, that when given a 64 bit sequential value, will hash to 8 bits uniformly.

I don't want to just use the least-significant byte as the hash value.

Comment: What do you mean by a "sequential value"?  Do you mean you literally just get the sequence "0 1 2 3 4 5..." in turn, and you want to hash each of these to an 8-bit value?

Comment: Would a check digit be appropriate? Such as MOD 10?

Comment: Yep. They're 64-bit autonumber database primary keys. The sequence may not start at 0, but from whatever the start value is, the sequence will just be +1 for each subsequent value.

Comment: *Why* don't you just want to use the least significant byte? If you're going to reject the most obvious approach, you should explain what's undesirable about it.

Comment: Agreed. If the numbers are sequential, then simply taking the low byte will keep the number of hash collisions to a minimum, so why would you not want that?

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm looking to avoid an obvious pattern between the input and output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general case of Oli Charlesworth's solution, you can select coprime with 256 and pre-multiply each byte from your input by that value and then `XOR` all values together. You'll still get uniform distribution, but for sequential inputs you'll get non-sequential output, for instance:

```
byte result = 0;
int q = 33149;
foreach (byte b in BitConverter.GetBytes(input)) result += (byte)(b * q);
```

For 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... it will get you 125, 250, 119, 244, 113, 238, etc

Comment: My answer will also give non-sequential output.

Comment: Agreed, starting from 256 your version will also get non-sequential results and for values greater than a few thousands it'll also 'look random'.

Answer (score 2):

Lacking any further information or constraints, one possibility is just to bitwise-XOR all of the 8 bytes together.  This will be uniform for a uniform input.

My C# is rusty, but in pseudocode:

```
byte hash = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    hash ^= (byte)(val >> (i*8));
}
```

Comment: There's no `uint8`, use `byte` instead ;)